# Error : ORA-01704: string literal too long. Dynamically assign CLOB to variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, clob

My problem is quite nontrivial.

I should execute PL/SQL script which  runs `INSERT INTO` query. It looks like:

```
DECLARE
newId NUMBER(38,0) := &1;
BEGIN
Insert into FOO ("ID", "DESCRIPTION")
values (newId+1, 'LARGE CLOB WHICH PRODUCES EXCEPTION');
-- A LOT OF INSERT QUERIES
END;
/
exit;
```

So, I found that it's a good idea to assign CLOB to VARCHAR2 variable as It could be 32767 bytes long. My goal is to do that for each `INSERT INTO` query. Like:

```
--assign CLOB to VARCHAR2 variable
-- INSERT variable instead of CLOB type
```

I want to point out that I have a lot of `INSERT INTO` queries in script, so I should reassign variable before each `INSERT INTO` query, how can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking - how to assign a value to a varchar2 PL/SQL variable? Are all your values less than 32k?

Comment: Read the oversize data from file into a database lob column or a plsql lob variable; or break the literal into chunks of size less than 32k, reassembling the parts with sql updates or by using the dbms_lob package.

Comment: It seems one of the things you are trying to do is to identify the clob values that are too large to be assigned to varchar2. You can do this in place, just use the length() function - which works perfectly fine for clob's. What version of Oracle do you use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the ORA-01704 because your string literal is more than 4000 bytes, which is the size limit for string literals in SQL calls. In PL/SQL the limit is 32k, so if all your values are less than that you can assign them to a PL/SQL variable and use that for the insert:

```
DECLARE
  newId NUMBER(38,0) := &1;
  newDescription varchar2(32767); -- or clob
BEGIN
  newDescription := 'LARGE CLOB WHICH PRODUCES EXCEPTION';
  Insert into FOO ("ID", "DESCRIPTION")
  values (newId+1, newDescription);

  newDescription := 'ANOTHER LARGE CLOB WHICH PRODUCES EXCEPTION';
  Insert into FOO ("ID", "DESCRIPTION")
  values (newId+1, newDescription);

  ...
END;
/
```

If any of the values are more than 32k you'll need a PL/SQL CLOB variable, and will need to construct that by appending shorted (<32k) string literals, which is messy.

Using multiple insert statements may not be the best way to go anyway. You might be able to use SQL*Loader or an external table to load the data more simply. Or you could read the values using `utl_file`, e.g. into the same PL/SQL variable, and then insert in a loop - which would be less code and easier to maintain.

You could also use a collection to hold the string values:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE stringTab IS table of varchar2(32767); -- or clob
  newDescriptions stringTab := new stringTab();
BEGIN
  newDescriptions.extend;
  newDescriptions(newDescriptions.last) := 'LARGE CLOB WHICH PRODUCES EXCEPTION';

  newDescriptions.extend;
  newDescriptions(newDescriptions.last) := 'ANOTHER LARGE CLOB WHICH PRODUCES EXCEPTION';

  forall i in newDescriptions.first..newDescriptions.last
    insert into FOO ("ID", "DESCRIPTION")
    values (&1 + 1, newDescriptions(i));
END;
/
```

... which will be a trade-off between performance and (maybe) readability, against memory usage by the collection. And you can populate that in the block, or again read the values into the collection from a file, if that's feasible for your situation.

---

You can still generate this from queries against an existing table, with something like:

```
set pages 0
set lines 32767
set long 32767
set define off

select 'DECLARE' || chr(10)
  || '  newId NUMBER(38,0) := &1;' || chr(10)
  || '  newDescription varchar2(32767);' || chr(10)
  || 'BEGIN'
from dual;

select '  newDescription := q''[' || description || ']'';' || chr(10)
  || '  newId := newId + 1;' || chr(10)
  || '  insert into FOO ("ID", "DESCRIPTION") values (newId, newDescription);' || chr(10)
from foo;

select 'END;' || chr(10)
  || '/' || chr(10)
  || 'exit'
from dual;

set define on
```

I've used [the alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) in case any of your string values contain single quotes, but you'll need to pick a suitable quote delimiter. And again this assumes none of your CLOB values exceeds 32k.

I'd also reconsider if you really want to do this with a script full of insert statements; if the data is coming from a table anyway then an export/import might be more appropriate.

Comment: Yeap.. I didn't mention that INSERT INTO query I get from client. I mean that I can add variables to this query but I am not typing CLOB variable, I just get it as text.

Comment: I can manipulate variables, any.
I can't change insert values, I get them as a result of previous query

Comment: You get the entire script as you've shown it, with the long string literals included in the values clause, and can't modify it? I'm confused. What is the previous query that gets the insert values? Is that run on the same DB, or one that you can link to, or can you only transfer data by file?

Comment: I have select query which generates this insert query.
Like Select ('Insert into .. values'field1, field2) FROM foo

Comment: @GrigoriyDidorenko - you can still generate the assignment and insert statements from a query like that. I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare a clob variable in PL/SQL. See the [lob semantics](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_plsql_semantics.htm) and the [DBMS_LOB](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i1016465) package to manipulate it. It can be something like:

```
DECLARE
   myLOBFromDatabase CLOB;
BEGIN
   SELECT lobComun INTO myLOBFromDatabase FROM table WHERE id=1;


   /* Manipulate lob wth dbms_lob package at will here */  

    Insert into FOO ("ID", "DESCRIPTION")
    values (newId+1, myLOBFromDatabase );

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a little strange resolve of this, but it works.

```
DECLARE 
JS CLOB;
BEGIN
  JS := TO_CLOB( 'THE FIRST PART OF CLOB SHOULD BE LESS THEN 32K
                  ......
                  ......'||
                 '....... 
                  THIS IS SECOND PART IS LESS THEN 32K TOO'||
                 '....... 
                  LAST PART');
END;
```

This way got me to insert more than 1M